# Resgatar valor de objeto

Tags: php, simplexml-load-string

Eu possuo um objeto assim:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 1bf7080ac1c04e4e9de924c0a7d9444d
)
```

Porém não consigo resgatar apenas o valor do mesmo. Já tentei das seguintes formas:

```
print_r($obj{0});
print_r($obj{'0'});
print_r($obj->{0});
print_r($obj->{'0'});
print_r($obj[0]);
print_r($obj['0']);
print_r($obj->[0]);
print_r($obj->['0']);
```

Mas não obtive sucesso!

Comment: Pq não converte em um array?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus boa, não havia pensado nisso. Isso de certa forma já resolve o meu problema. Valeu! ;) Mas eu ainda gostaria de saber como resgatar como Objeto.

Comment: Tente assim: `current($obj)`. o Current aponta para o indice corrente, ou seja, o primeiro.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus Perfeito! Adicione seu comentário como resposta. Pode servir para outras pessoas tb! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `current` que aponta para o índice `corrente` do `array`, nesse caso o índice `0`.

Ficaria assim:

`current($obj);`

Como alternativa, você pode converter para `array`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('seu_arquivo.xml');    
$string = json_encode($xml);    
$array = json_decode($string);
```